# odoo domain search "id in ids"

Tags: database, odoo, odoo-11

I have a model B with a Many2many field referencing model A.
Now given an id of model A, I try to get the records of B that reference it.

Is this possible with Odoo search domains? Is it possible doing some SQL query?

**Example**

```py
class A(models.Model):
    _name='module.a'

class B(models.Model):
    _name='module.b'
    a_ids = fields.Many2many('m.a')
```

I try to do something like

```py
a_id = 5
filtered_b_ids = self.env['module.b'].search([(a_id,'in','a_ids')])
```

However, this is not a valid search in Odoo. Is there a way to let the database do the search?
So far I fetch all records of B from the database and filter them afterward:

```py
all_b_ids = self.env['module.b'].search([])
filtered_b_ids = [b_id for b_id in b_ids if a_id in b_id.a_ids]
```

However, I want to avoid fetching not needed records and would like to let the database do the filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the equivalent Many2many field in A.

```py
class A(models.Model):
    _name='module.a'
    b_ids = fields.Many2many('module.b', 'rel_a_b', 'a_id', 'b_id')


class B(models.Model):
    _name='module.b'
    a_ids = fields.Many2many('module.a', 'rel_a_b', 'b_id', 'a_id')
```

In the field definition, the second argument is the name of the association table, and the two next ones are the name of the columns referencing the records of the two models. It's explained in the official ORM documentation.
Then you just have to do `my_a_record.b_ids`.

If you prefer doing an SQL request because you don't want to add a python field to A, you can do so by calling `self.env.cr.execute("select id from module_b b,  ...").fetchall()`. In your request you have to join the association table (so you need to specify a name for it and its columns, as described in my code extract, otherwise they are automatically named by Odoo and I don't know the rule).

I think it's still possible to use search domains without the field in A but it's tricky. You can try `search([('a_ids','in', [a_id])])` but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Good answer. Yes it is possible with your final domain.

Comment: Awesome! The contrary Many2many field is super powerful feature. I have the Odoo Cookbook but this was not well covered.

Comment: Indeed search([('a_ids','in', [a_id])]) works perfectly for me. What exactly does this check? Looking for ANY element in the list that is also in a_ids? Or must ALL elements in the list be also in a_ids?

Answer (score 0):

```
class A(models.Model):
    _name='module.a'

class B(models.Model):
    _name='module.b'
    a_ids = fields.Many2many('module.a')
```

Now you want to search a_id = 5 
To do so simply use browse or search ORM methods i.e,

```
a_id = 5
filtered_b_ids = self.env['module.b'].search([(a_id,'in',self.a_ids.ids)])
```

or

```
 a_id = 5
    filtered_b_ids = self.env['module.a'].search([(a_id)])
```

Comment: filtered_b_ids = self.env['module.a'].search([(a_id)]) is not what I want. This will return the record of ModelA with the database id a_id. But I want record of ModelB that references the ModelA with the database id a_id.

Comment: (a_id,'in',self.a_ids.ids)] is not a valid search tuple I think because it does not reference a database column.